# Compare file and remove duplicate

Tags: c#

I have two file:

File 1.txt

abc@ewr.com
xyc@df.co.nz
rte@pope.com
ssddsf@fdf.com

File 2.txt

rgt@ewr.com
xyc@df.co.nz
rte@pope.com
abc@fdf.com
sert@fd.com
tiffer@fg.com

I want first detect duplicate and then delete duplicate from File1.

How to do.

Answer (score 1):

If you read both into their own `List<string>` then you can do this:

```
// file1 is a List<string> representing each line of file1
// file2 is a List<string> representing each line of file2
List<string> file1WithoutDupes = (from line in file1
                                  where !file2.Contains(line)
                                  select line).ToList();
```

And you won't end up merging the two lists.

Answer (score 0):

One another solution is by using an hash table.

Load entries from first file in hash table having keys = file entries.
Then before inserting entries from second file check if the keys already exists or not.

Answer (score 0):

Provided you don't already have the contents of the files in a list, here's how you could do it:

```
var file1 = File.ReadAllLines(file1Path);
var file2 = File.ReadAllLines(file2Path);
var dupes = Array.FindAll(file1, line =>
    Array.Exists(file2, line2 => line2 == line));
var noDupes = Array.FindAll(file1, line =>
    !Array.Exists(dupes, line2 => line2 == line));
File.WriteAllLines(file1Path, noDupes); // write back to file1
```

However, if you have the contents of file1 and file2 stored in a `List<string>`, you could write:

```
// Option #1: LINQ, returns results
var dupes = file1.Intersect(file2);
var noDupes = file1.Except(dupes);
File.WriteAllLines(file1Path, noDupes.ToArray());

// Option #2: generic collection methods
List<string> dupes = file1.FindAll(item => file2.Contains(item));
file1.RemoveAll(item => dupes.Contains(item)); // affects original list
File.WriteAllLines(file1Path, file1.ToArray());
```

In .NET 4.0 you should be able to use the [File.ReadLines method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503(VS.100).aspx), which returns `IEnumerable<string>`, and have more flexibility than the string array returned by File.ReadAllLines. Also, the [WriteAllLines method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383693%28VS.100%29.aspx) is overloaded to accept an `IEnumerable<string>`, which would allow us to drop the `ToArray()` call seen in the above snippets.

**EDIT:** note that in both code samples you could skip the dupes part and go straight to determining the results of noDupes by using `file2` instead of the `dupes` variable in the Array and LINQ approaches, respectively. I left it in for clarity if you needed to refer to the dupes.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want the lines on file 1 that are not present in file 2. Try this then:

```
var lines1=File.ReadAllLines("File1.txt");
var lines2=File.ReadAllLines("File2.txt");
var file1OnlyLines=lines1.Except(lines2).ToList();
```